# impala queries fail

Tags: linux

1. `Couldn't open transport for p1i-hdp-srv12.lnt.com:22000 (connect() failed: Connection refused)`
2. `RPC client failed to connect: Couldn't open transport for p1i-hdp-srv09.lnt.com:22000 (connect() failed: Connection refused)`
3. `ExecQueryFInstances rpc query_id=d745512ef66df60d:ced351a700000000 failed: RPC client failed to connect: Couldn't open transport for p1i-hdp-srv09.lnt.com:22000 (connect() failed: Connection refused)`
4. `Failed to create thread SenderThread(1:1) in category DataStreamSender: boost::thread_resource_error: Resource temporarily unavailable`

To prevent the above errors I was told that the each Impala host should be configured like this:

```
echo 2000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
echo 2000000 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
echo 8000000 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

In `/etc/security/limits.conf` add

```
impala soft nproc 262144
impala hard nproc 262144
```

Can anyone tell me if this is safe?
Is there any limitation I need to follow?
Any side effects?
After executing these changes, do I need to restart anything?
Are there any other things which I need to check or configure before making these changes?

Comment: Have you asked the person who gave you this advice? What did they tell you? Why don't you trust them?

Comment: I am just trying to get a second opinion